# Divergence of a sequence $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to test the following sequence $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n\cdot n}{n+1}$ on convergence.
I can see that it is divergent, but unfortunately I have no idea, how to show it in a clear mathematical proof.
Is there someone who can help me, please?

Comment: Why do you think that's divergent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\{a_{2n}\}$ converges to $1$, while $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ converges to $-1$. If the sequence were to converge, all subsequences would have to converge to the same limit also.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $n \geq 1$, you have
$$
a_n = \frac{{(-1)}^n n}{n + 1} = \frac{{(-1)}^n n}{n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)} = \frac{{(-1)}^n}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}
$$
and given $\varepsilon > 0$, exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, then
$$
|a_n - {(-1)}^n| < \varepsilon\mbox{.}
$$
Therefore $\{a_n\}$ converges if $\{{(- 1)}^n\}$ converges. So $\{a_n\}$ doesn't converge because $\{{(- 1)}^n\}$ doesn't converge.